# Redirect to ssl site using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I am having a domain example.com and installed SSLfor www.example.com. I want to create a htaccess file for the below rules:

```
Redirect all traffic from http://example.com to https://www.example.com
Redirect all traffic from http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
```

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. A search for `Redirect to ssl site using htaccess` should give you everything you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like this in the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that may already be there.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I got : Internal Server Error

Comment: I tried the below :
`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`
`# Turn mod_rewrite on`
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteBase /`

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
`RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`
but it redirecting `http://domain` to `https://domain` and not to `https://www.domain`

Comment: @Gopu You want what I have, I had a typo (spelled "rewrite" wrong)